# NetworkX - How to write to csv multiple centrality metrics

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using NetworkX to calculate some centrality metrics for a network. How can i save these results into a csv file, in table format? I can only print the result in the terminal.

```
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(4,6)])


DEGREE_CENTRALITY = nx.degree_centrality(G)
EIGENVECTOR = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G)
KATZ = nx.katz_centrality_numpy(G)
CLOSENESS_CENTRALITY = nx.closeness_centrality(G)
BETWEENNESS_CENTRALITY = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
CLUSTCOEF = nx.clustering(G)
```

*print the result in the terminal:*

```
      for n in G: print ("%s, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f"%(n, DEGREE_CENTRALITY[n], 
    EIGENVECTOR[n], KATZ[n], CLOSENESS_CENTRALITY[n], BETWEENNESS_CENTRALITY[n], 
CLUSTCOEF[n]))

            ... 
            1, 0.400000, 0.456986, 0.408764, 0.500000, 0.000000, 1.000000
            2, 0.400000, 0.456986, 0.408764, 0.500000, 0.000000, 1.000000
            3, 0.600000, 0.584217, 0.448883, 0.714286, 0.600000, 0.333333
            4, 0.600000, 0.417117, 0.441314, 0.714286, 0.700000, 0.000000
            5, 0.200000, 0.183073, 0.367131, 0.454545, 0.000000, 0.000000
            6, 0.200000, 0.183073, 0.367131, 0.454545, 0.000000, 0.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stick it into a pandas dataframe and use `to_csv` method.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(4,6)])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    DEGREE_CENTRALITY      = nx.degree_centrality(G),
    EIGENVECTOR            = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G),
    KATZ                   = nx.katz_centrality_numpy(G),
    CLOSENESS_CENTRALITY   = nx.closeness_centrality(G),
    BETWEENNESS_CENTRALITY = nx.betweenness_centrality(G),
    CLUSTCOEF              = nx.clustering(G),
))

df.index += 1
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```